Error 400 This user is not allowed to access non-existent class, MongoDB
The Issue
I am receiving this error whenever I run my code:

Error 400 This user is not allowed to access non-existent class: CEDIS


exports.SaveCedis = async (data) => {
  
  
  console.log(data);

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var Table = Parse.Object.extend("CEDIS");
    var object = new Table();

    object.set("name", data.cedis_name);
    object.set("transport_cedis", {
      price_truck: parseInt(data.transport_cedis.price_truck),
      price_ship: parseInt(data.transport_cedis.price_ship),
      price_plane: parseInt(data.transport_cedis.price_plane),
      time_truck: parseInt(data.transport_cedis.time_truck),
      time_ship: parseInt(data.transport_cedis.time_ship),
      time_plane: parseInt(data.transport_cedis.time_plane),
    });
    object.set("transport_customer", {
      price_truck: parseInt(data.transport_customer.price_truck),
      price_ship: parseInt(data.transport_customer.price_ship),
      price_plane: parseInt(data.transport_customer.price_plane),
      time_truck: parseInt(data.transport_customer.time_truck),
      time_ship: parseInt(data.transport_customer.time_ship),
      time_plane: parseInt(data.transport_customer.time_plane),
    });
    object.set("distance_cedis", parseInt(data.distance_cedis));
    object.set("distance_customer", parseInt(data.distance_customer));
    object.set("price_storage", parseInt(data.price_storage));
    object.set("storage_space", parseInt(data.storage_space));

    object.save().then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(object)
        resolve({ type: "AGREGAR", data: result, error: null });
      },
      (error) => {
        resolve({ type: "AGREGAR", data: null, error: error.message });
      }
    );
  });
};


Personal thoughts on where the problem lies
I believe it has something to do with access control in MongoDB.
I created the collection manually and created a record with the mongosh terminal, but when running the code I receive the exception mentioned.
What have I tried
I tried making the collection manually, and using logs to understand were the function breaks, up to posting the content into the database the content is reaching the function correctly, but the save method isn't working.
